# Write a string to a file from php

Tags: c#, php

```
<?php
$my_file = "uploads/dir1/myText.txt"

$current = file_get_contents($my_file);

$new_text = http_get_request_body();

file_put_contents($new_text, $current);
?>
```

`$myText.txt` is already on the server. And I would like to change it to the string I send it.

I am sending a request to the php file from a C# script like so:

`webClient.UploadString(linkToMyWebsitesUploadPHPFile, "POST", "here is my new text");`

I am getting an internal server error 500.

What is the problem?

Comment: i think, file_put_contents() is the one that generate error since the first parameter should be filename according to php manual... not new content you want to put.

Comment: @Moch.Rasyid In that case, how can I just create a file with the string I want to put in it?

Comment: try subtitute $new_text with $my_file or filename you want to write and switch $current with $new_text since you want to write whatever new text is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal server error 500 it has many reasons to occur  ..if You getting this then maybe has any error in your script.Or maybe Others reason...You can check **write permission** in uploads/dir1/ directory.

You can Check .htaccess on your  server

You can check Apache **error_log** it better for you   then you  find out the error. and btw you have to end  the first line statement  which is

```
$my_file = "uploads/dir1/myText.txt";
```

instead of

```
$my_file = "uploads/dir1/myText.txt"
```

after  that you have to check [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
then [http-get-request-body](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php)